# Работа с текстом, граммотное оформление

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, работа-с-текстом

Доброе время суток. Хотел бы узнать, как в `html` грамотно записать код, чтобы потом обратиться к этим строкам в `css`. Я думаю, что через теги `<p>` с классами к каждой строке, но это слишком нагружено будет выглядеть и проблемно. Иными словами, как сделать то, что на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "нагруженно будет выглядить и проблемно"? У вас 3 элемента с разными стилями, вы хотите сделать все за 1 строчку кода?

Comment: Можно каждую строку сунуть в `span`  и обернуть это тего `p`... скорее не можно , а нужно

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, все понял, все просто

```html
<p>
  <span class="name">NAME HERE</span>
  <span class="surname">SURNAME</span>
  <span class="job">graphic design</span>
</p>
```